# Segue is Not Performing on Search Result

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a `UITableView` that displays an `NSArray`. A `UIView` is showed by clicking on each table cell using a `segue identifier`. When I add a search bar, for some reason I can't get to that `UIView` by clicking on searched cells anymore.

I did this experiment

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue");

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"view"]) {

        NSLog(@"segue = view");
    }

}
```

I run the app and directly tried to search and then click on any table cell. **I got no logs.**

When I don't search and just click on a table cell directly. I got both logs.

```
prepareForSegue
segue = view
```

What can be the problem? please give me solution. Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Recipe *recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = recipe.name;

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];

    return [sectionInfo name];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"view"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
        Recipe *recipe = nil;

        if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            recipe = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            recipe = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipe = recipe;
    }
}
```

Comment: call performSegue method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.And also check didSelectRowAtIndexPath is getting called after search.Update your question with tableview delegate methods too.

Comment: Are you able to see the Target View Controller ? And also check if there is a segue identifier named "view".

Comment: Where is called the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`?

Comment: @Suhail I don't use didSelectRowAtIndexPath meth. I updated my question with tableview methods and original prepareForSegue. Thanks.

Comment: @iCoder I see the target view controller if I click on each table cell directly. If I search through the search bar I can't get to the target view controller. There's a segue identifier named "view" between UITableViewController cells and a UIViewController.

Comment: @Larme It's not called anywhere. Where should I call it? The problem is, the segue **is** performed if I don't search. But if I search it wont not perform anymore.

Comment: do one thing.drag the segue from tableView to destination viewController instead of from tableview cell.And call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @Suhail I don't use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Segues can only be between two controllers that are present in the storyboard. The search results table is not in the storyboard, so you need to push or present it in code.